# Mapping network drives with script

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, script, shell-script

I'm attempting to use a script to

1. unmap a drive
2. clear the cached credentials used to map that drive
3. map the drive again using different user credentials.

In Windows 7 the following script worked for me

```
@echo off
net use Z: /delete /y >nul
net stop LanmanWorkstation /y >nul
net start LanmanWorkstation >nul
timeout 1 >nul
net use Z: \\path\to\directory
```

This script is intended to unmount what is mapped to Z. Then clear the cached credentials used to mount z. Then remap the drive using another user's credentials.

When I run this on windows 10, the net stop and net start throw access denied errors. I have tried creating a shortcut of the script and setting the shortcut to always run as admin, but this option is greyed out on my box probably by group policy settings.

I am attempting to find a way to achieve this same unmap/map solution and am currently exploring options granted through powershell. My current attempt in powershell is using

`mount -Name "z" -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\path\to\directory" -Persist`

The map needs to be persistent so that the drive appears in windows explorer. 
This command works as it should when I run it in powershell, but double clicking on the file to run it does not map the drive, probably because of access issues. I'm new to powershell and am still learning it, so I don't know all options available to me. Does anyone know a way to achieve the effect I'm going for?

Answer (score 1):

See the below ---

[Clear Windows Credential Cache](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile)

> The utility to delete cached credentials is hard to find. It stores
>   both certificate data and also user passwords.
>
> Open a command prompt, or enter the following in the run command

```
 rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

> There is also a command-line utility:

```
C:\> cmdkey /?
```

> Creates, displays, and deletes stored user names and passwords.

Drive mappings are just a pain historically. Well, you know... ;-}

Net use was not the only option, as you could use WScript in VBS or WMIC to do this as well. So, sure PowerShell can do WMI for this.

[#PSTip Create mapped network drive using WScript.Network](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/21/pstip-create-mapped-network-drive-using-wscript-network/)

> An example of how a drive can be mapped can be seen here:

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive('Z:','\\server\folder')
```

> This will not map the drive persistently. In other words, the drive
>   will disappear after reboot or when a user logs out. To ensure the
>   drive mapping is persistent a third argument should be added–a Boolean
>   value set to true:

```
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive('Z:','\\server\folder',$true)
```

Using the -persist switch is the PowerShell option for drive stickiness, but you also have the Smb cmdlets, since v3.

```
Get-Command -Name '*smb*'

CommandType     Name                   Version    Source
-----------     ----                   -------    ------
...         
Function        Get-SmbGlobalMapping   2.0.0.0    SmbShare
Function        Get-SmbMapping         2.0.0.0    SmbShare
...        
Function        Get-SmbShare           2.0.0.0    SmbShare
Function        Get-SmbShareAccess     2.0.0.0    SmbShare
....
Function        New-SmbMapping         2.0.0.0    SmbShare
...        
Function        New-SmbShare           2.0.0.0    SmbShare
...            
Function        Remove-SmbShare        2.0.0.0    SmbShare
...           
Function        Set-SmbShare           2.0.0.0    SmbShare
...
```

See also:
[Powershell: Map/Unmap Network drive on a remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340684/powershell-map-unmap-network-drive-on-a-remote-computer)

As for this...

> I run it in powershell, but double clicking on the file to run it does
>   not map the drive, probably because of access issues.

… it's not a thing. .ps1 are by default associated with notepad or other text editor. This I by design. Sure, you can change that association, but don't. Users double click just about anything, and that can lead to a bunch of real issues security / risk management / operationally for you and your org.

There are ways to double click to run, with / without elevated permissions:

1. The whole association thing, just don't do that.
2. Call a .ps1 from a bat/ cmd file.

Though I really have always felt this, double click to run even for even .bat, .vbs, .cmd and they just run was a bad thing, well before PowerShell was a thing. Yet, industry got in to that habit and thus hard to get folks off of it.

3. Create a custom shortcut, properly configured to double click to
   run.

Example:

```
# specify the path to your PowerShell script
$ScriptPath = "C:\test\test.ps1"

# create a lnk file
$shortcutPath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($ScriptPath, "lnk")
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($ScriptPath)

# create a new shortcut
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$scut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutPath)

# launch the script with powershell.exe:
$scut.TargetPath = "powershell.exe"

# skip profile scripts and enable execution policy for this one call
# IMPORTANT: specify only the script file name, not the complete path
$scut.Arguments = "-noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file ""$filename"""

# IMPORTANT: leave the working directory empty. This way, the 
# shortcut uses relative paths 
$scut.WorkingDirectory = ""

# optinally specify a nice icon
$scut.IconLocation = "$env:windir\system32\shell32.dll,162"

# save shortcut file
$scut.Save()

# open shortcut file in File Explorer
explorer.exe /select, $ShortcutPath
```

4. Turn our script into an .exe using this MS PowerShellGallery.com
   tool.

[PS2EXE-GUI: "Convert" PowerShell Scripts to EXE Files with GUI](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5)

So, you have options. Which you choose is a matter of operational allowances, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the options. It's been crazy at work and I haven't had the chance to try this yet. I will let you know how I get along.

Comment: No worries, hopefully one will get you there.